# TexShop inconsistent behavior

Tags: templates, texshop

I'm a newbie to Tex, cannot understand how I used MS word soooo long. Here's my first question.

I'm using MacTex which came with TexShop, which so far seems useful. TexShop has a basic LaTex template which until recently worked just fine (i.e. if I hit "typeset" it produced the PDF of a simple document. Here is the template:

```
\documentclass[11pt, oneside]{article}      % use "amsart" instead of "article" for AMSLaTeX format
\usepackage{geometry}                       % See geometry.pdf to learn the layout options. There are lots.
\geometry{letterpaper}                          % ... or a4paper or a5paper or ... 
%\geometry{landscape}                       % Activate for for rotated page geometry
%\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}          % Activate to begin paragraphs with an empty line rather than an indent
\usepackage{graphicx}               % Use pdf, png, jpg, or epsÂ§ with pdflatex; use eps in DVI mode
                                % TeX will automatically convert eps --> pdf in pdflatex        
\usepackage{amssymb}

\title{Brief Article}
\author{The Author}
%\date{}                            % Activate to display a given date or no date

\begin{document}
\maketitle
%\section{}
%\subsection{}



\end{document}
```

Suddendly the template stopped working. But 1-TexShop processes other Tex files just fine, and 2-the offending template above works just fine in Latexian. When I hit "typeset' in TexShop I get the image below. I re-installed MacTex, to no avail. Grateful for any suggestions. Apologies if this is not the right venue for this question.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: I just run the 'template' above on Linux with `pdflatex` (TeXLive 2014) command line -- without errors. Either there are some typos or your TeXShop configuration/TeX installation is broken

Comment: Delete the `aux` files and try again.

Comment: I suspect you may have written a `letter` previously, and some of the `letter`-related content is still contained in an old `.aux` file. Delete the `.aux` and recompile.

Comment: Note that a clue that the problem is likely in the `.aux` file or similar is that the error message complains about something involving 'Professor Jones' but that text is not part of the template. Usually this means you have stale generated files somehow associated with your `.tex` file.

Comment: Thank you All; deleting the .aux did it. I had naively assumed that all relevant files would be overwritten when I recompiled.

Comment: @FernanJaramillo the aux file is read from the previous run as that is how latex resolves cross references and page numbers etc, but the assumption is that an aux file of the same name does in fact relate to the same document:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Close as off topic since could be resolved by deleting aux?

Comment: @Johannes_B went for dup (a bit marginal, but perhaps closer than OT)